# how to reverse min and max value in percentage

Tags: math

I need help to solve this algorithm, I am stuck in this.

how to reverse the min and max value for percentage.

I want to 0 as 100 % and 100 as 0%?

anybody can help me to solve this algorithm ?

Comment: I tried it with calculator but the result is not the same as you described . 1 / 0.10 = 10

Comment: (100 - 0)/100 = 100%,  (100 - 100)/100 = 0%

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about arithmetic, not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract from 100.

To flip 80 and 20:

- 100 - 80 = 20
- 100 - 20 = 80

If you work with decimals, subtract from 1:

- 1.0 - 0.2 = 0.8
- 1.0 - 0.8 = 0.2

Comment: What if there were more than two items?